# get the value of an input near the href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a jquery statement

Here is the HTML code:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="variant_title">2014 - CYZ51P/18</td>
    <td class="">1</td>
    <td>
        <input name="price[114][1]" value="265700" class="form-control input_prices unmask" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        <a data-year="2014" data-variant="CYZ51P/18" href="#" class="analyseItemChannel green">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="variant_title">2013 - NMR71E22/24</td>
    <td class="">0</td>
    <td>
        <input name="price[111][1]" value="0" class="form-control input_prices unmask" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        <a data-year="2013" data-variant="NMR71E22/24" href="#" class="analyseItemChannel green">
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, what I am looking for is when the user click on the (a href) I need to get the data which is in the input near that (a href).

Here is my jquery, and what didn't work for me:

```
$("a.analyseItemChannel").on('click', function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    price = $('.input_prices', this).val();
    console.log(price);
    price = $(this).closest('.input_prices').val();
    console.log(price);
});
```

Any suggestions, 
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead of [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) in this case.

`prev`: *Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.*

`closest`: *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*

```
$("a.analyseItemChannel").on('click', function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var price = $(this).prev('.input_prices').val();
    console.log(price);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `prev()` function in jQuery to get to the **previous sibling**:

```js
$("a.analyseItemChannel").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  price = $(this).prev('.input_prices').val();
  console.log(price);
  price = $(this).prev('.input_prices').val();
  console.log(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="variant_title">2014 - CYZ51P/18</td>
    <td class="">1</td>
    <td>
      <input name="price[114][1]" value="265700" class="form-control input_prices unmask" autocomplete="off" type="text">
      <a data-year="2014" data-variant="CYZ51P/18" href="#" class="analyseItemChannel green">A</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="variant_title">2013 - NMR71E22/24</td>
    <td class="">0</td>
    <td>
      <input name="price[111][1]" value="0" class="form-control input_prices unmask" autocomplete="off" type="text">
      <a data-year="2013" data-variant="NMR71E22/24" href="#" class="analyseItemChannel green">A</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**And please close the `</a>` tag.**

Answer (score 0):

check if this is what you want (navigating to the parent first)

```js
$("a.analyseItemChannel").on('click', function (event)
    {
     event.preventDefault();
    
     price = $(this).prev().val();
     console.log(price);
     //price = $(this).closest('.input_prices').val();
     //console.log(price);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <tr role="row" class="odd">
     <td class="variant_title">2014 - CYZ51P/18</td>
     <td class="">1</td>
     <td>
      <input name="price[114][1]" value="265700" class="form-control input_prices unmask" autocomplete="off" type="text" />
      <a data-year="2014" data-variant="CYZ51P/18" href="#" class="analyseItemChannel green">link1</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
     <td class="variant_title">2013 - NMR71E22/24</td>
     <td class="">0</td>
     <td>
      <input name="price[111][1]" value="0" class="form-control input_prices unmask" autocomplete="off" type="text">
      <a data-year="2013" data-variant="NMR71E22/24" href="#" class="analyseItemChannel green">link2</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Why did you add the next one as well?

Comment: sorry, actually wasn't paying attention, now fixed some anchor tags and switched to more proper prev() as suggested by others

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this.

```
$("a.analyseItemChannel").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //using siblings()
    var price = $(this).siblings('.input_prices').first().val();
    console.log(price);

    //using prev()
    price = $(this).prev('.input_prices').val();
    console.log(price);       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click','a.analyseItemChannel', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var nextInput = $(this).next().filter('input');
      var prevInput = $(this).prev().filter('input');

      if(nextInput.length > 0){
         var price = nextInput.val();
         console.log(price);
      }
      if(prevInput.length > 0){
         var price = prevInput.val();
         console.log(price);
      }
});
```